# How do I list specific lines using awk?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file that is sorted like the following:

```
2 Good
2 Hello
3 Goodbye
3 Begin
3 Yes
3 No
```

I want to search for the highest value in the file and display what is one the line?

```
3 Goodbye
3 begin
3 Yes
3 No
```

How would I do this?

Comment: how much lines are you expecting ? (100K is not same as 1K..) is it a must to do it in a single command ? or possible to wrap it in a script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat file.txt | sort -r | awk '{if ($1>=prev) {print $0; prev=$1}}'

```
3 Yes
3 No
3 Goodbye
3 Begin
```

Assuming **file.txt** contains

```
2 Good
2 Hello
3 Goodbye
3 Begin
3 Yes
3 No
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Unless you have a stable sort, this may change the order of elements...

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{if(max<$1) max=$1; next} $1==max' file{,}

3 Goodbye
3 Begin
3 Yes
3 No
```

double-pass, find the maximum and filter out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

First get the highest value in the file into a variable.  Considering the file is already sorted, pickup the last line in the file.  Then parse out the number using awk.

```
highest=`tail -1 file.list|awk '{print $1}'`
```

Then grep the file using that value.

```
grep "^${highest} " file.list
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. I am only using `awk` as required in the question:

```
awk 'BEGIN {v=0} {l = l "\n" $0} {if ($1>v) {l = $0; v = $1}} END {print l}' file.txt
```

The variable `v` is initialized (before parsing the file) to 0. Then each line is read and kept in memory; if the first field (`$1`) is greater than `v`, then update `v` and empty what is in `l`. At the end, just print the content of `l`.

Comment: but this will print only the first line "3 Goodbye"

Comment: @nabeel Right. Updated.

Comment: `v=0` is not explicitly needed, it's the default.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think.

```
awk '/^3/' file

3 Goodbye
3 Begin
3 Yes
3 No
```